# Is it possible to make __init__ files describe parent package dynamically?

Tags: python, architecture, package

So I have a tree of modules and packages, it's two levels deep.

My goal, at top level, in `main.py`, is to refer to a sub-module using this syntax

```
import pkg1

pkg1.bebrs.fn_3.run()
```

the dot, dot, dot notation is very important to me.

[image: Here's my tree:]

inside the `__init__.py` inside the bebrs folder, my init states
`from pkg1.bebrs import fn_3`

it explicitly states the name of parent and current package.

Is there any way to type the `pkg1` and `bebrs` in a more generalized way inside `from pkg1.bebrs import fn_3`? I wish I could just put generic `__init__.py` files and be able to import nested stuff with dot notation instead of having a very explicit nested import inside each nested `__init__.py` file.